# Dúvida com a window function no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Tenho um trabalho para a faculdade e estou com uma dúvida em um exercício que tenho que usar as window functions pra fazer a consulta correta.

Essa é a minha query:

```
SELECT pais, modelo, fabricante.nome, (venda.valor - automovel.preco) AS lucro,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pais ORDER BY pais, (venda.valor - automovel.preco))
FROM automovel, venda, fabricante 
WHERE automovel.codigo = venda.automovel AND fabricante.codigo = automovel.fabricante;
```

Essa é a saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema que estou tendo é que eu devo limitar para aparecerem somente os 2 automóveis de cada país dos mais lucrativos, mas não estou conseguindo. Eu pesquisei sobre o RANGE | ROWS BETWEEN e tal mas não consegui utilizá-lo.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: SELECT * FROM (
SELECT pais, modelo, fabricante.nome, (venda.valor - automovel.preco) AS lucro,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pais ORDER BY pais, (venda.valor - automovel.preco)) AS posicao
FROM automovel, venda, fabricante 
WHERE automovel.codigo = venda.automovel AND fabricante.codigo = automovel.fabricante) WHERE posicao <= 2;

Comment: Muito obrigado @FilipeL.Constante. Funcionou direitinho.

Comment: Coloquei como resposta, se possível marque como correta. Isso pode ajudar outros usuários que possam ter essa mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use desta forma que dará certo:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT pais, modelo, fabricante.nome, (venda.valor - automovel.preco) AS lucro, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pais ORDER BY pais, (venda.valor - automovel.preco)) AS posicao FROM automovel, venda, fabricante WHERE automovel.codigo = venda.automovel AND fabricante.codigo = automovel.fabricante) WHERE posicao <= 2;
```